# Strange behavior of SwiftUI TextField (MacOS)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of TextFields using SwiftUI on a MacOS application (XCode 11.0 stable, CoreData), probably due to some misconceptions on my side regarding SwiftUI dataflow.

### Implementation

Please consider this basic Master/Detail View setup:

- Model: `Account`
- Container: `ContentView`
- Master: `AccountListView`
- Detail: `AccountEditView`

```
final class Account: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
            @NSManaged var id: UUID
            @NSManaged var name: String
        }

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            AccountListView()
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
        .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: nil, maxWidth: nil, minHeight: 300, idealHeight: nil, maxHeight: nil, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}

struct AccountListView: View {

    @FetchRequest(entity: Account.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    var accounts: FetchedResults<Account>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(accounts) { account in
                NavigationLink (destination: AccountEditView(account: account)) {
                    Text(account.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AccountEditView: View {

    @ObservedObject var account: Account

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Account Name", text: $account.name)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

### Issue

The views are populated correctly. Selecting an account in list view properly updates the textfield in detail view.

However as soon as I edit the textfield value, things go strange:

- When the detail view is newly updated, the textfield loses focus after the first entered character. The account name in list view is properly updated (showing the single character entered)
- When I'm entering the textfied again, I can type more characters without losing focus (again, the account name in the list view is update)
- As soon as I press enter, the TextField's value restores to the old value, while the list view's value remains at the updated value.
- When switching back and forth between different account entries, the detail view shows the correct values. So the model object was properly updated.

### My questions:

1. Why does the TextField lose focus when entering a single character for the first time
2. Why does the TextField restore it's previous value (and not the model value) when commiting the change

Sorry for the lengthy question...

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? Seeing the same thing.

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found a solution?

Comment: maybe this question needs a few more upvotes?

Comment: I didn't really investigate it further and as far as I remember and I did not find a solution. Back the I thought the reason was a flawed approach on my side. I'm actually surprised someone else ran into this issue as well...

Comment: I'm running into the same issue as well, I'll submit a Radar though since it seems like others are having a similar problem but no solutions

Answer (score 0):

The coredata attributes are a different kind of optionals. So we need to define getter and setter inside the Model class to convert their behavior.

If your Entity's code gen is not manual/none, add this following code in contentview

```
extension Account {
    var wrappedName: String {
        get { name ?? "Unknown"}
        set { name = newValue }
    }
}
```

then replace all the `account.name` with `account.wrappedName`

*P.S. This is tested and worked in XCode 11.4 on MacOS 10.5*